# Bash auto complete for environment variables

Tags: 11.04, bash, environment-variables

The bash autocomplete feature does not seem to work with environment variables in 11.04. 
The current behavior is indicated below

```
export SCRIPT=/home/user/script
cd $SCRIPT/<tab>
```

results in a backslash (`\`) being added before `$SCRIPT` i.e. the prompt becomes

```
cd \$SCRIPT/
```

Same thing happens if `cd` is substituted with `ls` or any other command

Also, if there is an executable file in the path contained in $SCRIPT and I want to run that

```
$SCRIPT/<tab>
```

Bash does not show the options inside the folder (regardless of whether there is a single file or multiple files/directories inside the path contained in the environment variables).

In other words, autocomplete does not work with environment variables.

Comment: Here's the [bug in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/778627).

Comment: I think it does not have to do with the bash version (4.1 or 4.2). I've just installed bash-4.1 from sources and used it instead of the 4.2.24 (Ubuntu 12.04's version; installed from sources so i don't have to 'hold back' the package at each sys upgrade) and the behaviour is exactly the same. Very, very annoying...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in an old unsupported release. The bug is described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/778627) and has been fixed in 12.04 and later

Comment: @WarrenHill This may be off-topic because it's about a bug (and I've voted to close it for that reason). That the bug is in an unsupported release is irrelevant though--we don't close old questions *that have answers* as off-topic when the affected release's EoL date comes along. Only new/unanswered EoL questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 18):

To get the old behaivior back, use the command

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

or include it in your `.bashrc`

If you use the same .bashrc with different versions of bash, use

```
if ((BASH_VERSINFO[0] >= 4)) && ((BASH_VERSINFO[1] >= 2))
    then shopt -s direxpand
fi
```

Comment: That test will fail for bash 5.0 and 5.1.

Comment: Try `shopt -s direxpand 2>/dev/null || true` or `shopt | grep -q '^direxpand\b' && shopt -s direxpand` (if you don't want to ignore errors). [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/498857/278323)

Answer (score 17):

This bug was introduced in bash 4.2. There's a lengthy thread about it here:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00274.html

In short, Chet Ramey, the developer of bash, isn't sure how to go about fixing it yet.

Comment: Is there a way to revert to bash 4.1 ?

Comment: A fix is on the way: Chet added a "direxpand" shopt to restore the old behavior. It's not in Oneiric yet.

Comment: It's surprising to me that so few people have complained about this.  It's a big change from the way bash has worked for a number of years.

Answer (score 8):

The workaround suggested in http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00274.html is:

1. use `<Tab>`to auto-complete your environment variable s.t. you command line says `cd $MYVAR`
2. hit `<Esc>`+`<Ctrl>-E` to expand the current command line i.e. substitute `$MYVAR` by its value, the path
3. add a `/` and then enjoy `<Tab>` auto-completion as usual

This assumes you are in emacs mode (`set -o emacs`) and have `bash_completion` set up sensibly for `cd` (e.g. `complete -o nospace -F _cd cd`).

Unfortunately this doesn't work in vi mode (`set -o vi`) because command line expansion is not available then.

Answer (score 2):

After typing the shell variable

```
cd $SCRIPT/
```

type Cntrl-Alt-E.  This expands the variable

```
cd /home/user/script/
```

This does work with EDITOR=vi in Fedora 16.